# Why are calculations included in a GROUP BY in SQL?

Tags: sql, function, group-by

Is there ever a reason to include a function in the GROUP BY?

I see in in code and even in some instructions but have never been explained why, outside of it's easier to copy from the SELECT then typing it again.

Example:

```
SELECT 
    ProductName,
    IFF (UnitsInStock > 0, 'true', 'false) AS InStock
    COUNT(ProductID)
FROM Products
GROUP BY ProductName, IFF (UnitsInStock > 0, 'true', 'false)
```

I have started removing the functions in all my coding:

```
GROUP BY ProductName, UnitsInStock
```

Is there a reason to keep the full expression?

Answer (score 2):

grouping by  `IFF (UnitsInStock > 0, 'true', 'false)` produces -at most- two rows per product, grouping by `UnitsInStock ' produces row per unique value of the UnitsInStock.

Comment: This is also a likely by-effect from the codechanges OP is making

Comment: Some products (Teradata, for example) accept column aliases to be used on the GROUP BY clause; for those products one can `GROUP BY InStock` (or even a column number), but the Question didn't tag a particular product.

Comment: Is it an alias or is it a function? That really depends on the product (but also on the outcome)

Answer (score 0):

There are *many* articles out there (and training material to boot) about this subject, but the explanation is fairly straightforward really.

Keep in mind that (T-) SQL is not Turing-proof, it does not actually compiles to code - it transcribes your input - and therefor what comes in must go out - so if you input something SQL cannot "find" by itself, you need to reproduce it.

You *can not* `GROUP BY` InStock, because there is no InStock to use : you use a temporary "variable"  created by the function (it is not a *variable*, that's a lie, but for sake of argument keep that metaphor in mind).

EDIT: I want to point out @userMT has a good point, when you actually remove that code there is a good chance you might get more problems then you're bargaining for

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the RDBMS you're using and for some of those what settings you use, however the SQL standard allows grouping by column *numbers*:

```
SELECT 
    ProductName,
    IFF (UnitsInStock > 0, 'true', 'false) AS InStock
    COUNT(ProductID)
FROM Products
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Most RBDMSs support this, and this is how I *always* code.

It's completely safe because if you get the numbers wrong (too many, too few, etc), the statement will cause a syntax error, and referring to the columns by their expression adds no value.